# Reducing Record Returns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that is functioning normally for the most part, but per the screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i114p.jpg) and the sample below, I have encountered the following issues:

1) The Expr1 column is returning the correct totals that I requested via the Query, but there is repetition, as you can see, via COMPANY. Using DISTINCT hasn't helped and my subquery is how I retrieved the total delineated by COMPANY, but it's still showing repeated values.

2) Advice on how to just get one row per COMPANY with the total amount of Expr1 is what I'm shooting for. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
    SELECT Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE, 
           Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
           Activity.PRODUCT_CODE, 
           Activity.DESCRIPTION, 
           Name.ID, 
           Name.MEMBER_TYPE, 
           Name.STATUS,             
           Name.COMPANY, 
           Demo_Chapter.CH_COL_REGION, 
           Demo_Ch_Membership.CM_CURRENT_INIT, 
           Demo_Chapter.CH_CHAP_NUMBER,
           (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(a2.PRODUCT_CODE) AS Expr1
           FROM Activity AS a2 INNER JOIN
           Name AS n2 ON a2.ID = n2.ID
           WHERE (n2.COMPANY = Name.COMPANY)
           AND (a2.PRODUCT_CODE = 'aaol') 
           AND (a2.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102)
           AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-31 00:00:00', 102))
           GROUP BY n2.COMPANY) AS Expr1
           FROM Name INNER JOIN
            Demo_Individual ON Name.ID = Demo_Individual.ID 
           INNER JOIN
           Activity ON Name.ID = Activity.ID 
           INNER JOIN
           Demo_Chapter ON Name.CO_ID = Demo_Chapter.ID 
           INNER JOIN
           Demo_Ch_Membership ON Name.CO_ID = Demo_Ch_Membership.ID
           WHERE (Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'COL') 
           AND (Name.STATUS IN ('A', 'ABR')) 
           AND (Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('FIDELITY', 'FIDELITYOL')) 
           AND (Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-31 00:00:00', 102))
           AND (Activity.PRODUCT_CODE = 'aaol')
```

Here is a sample of the output (note repeated information):

```
CH_CHAP_NUMBER   COMPANY        CH_Col_REGION    CM_CURRENT_INIT    Expr1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    024         Omega Chapter      REG_5              160            121
    024         Omega Chapter      REG_5              160            121
    161        Zeta Rho Chapter    REG_3              282            162
    161        Zeta Rho Chapter    REG_3              282            162
    161        Zeta Rho Chapter    REG_3              282            162
    etc
```

Desired output would be as follows:

```
CH_CHAP_NUMBER   COMPANY        CH_Col_REGION    CM_CURRENT_INIT    Expr1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    024         Omega Chapter      REG_5              160            121
    161        Zeta Rho Chapter    REG_3              282            162
    etc
```

Broader Complete output:

```
ACTIVITY_TYPE TRANSACTION_DATE        PRODUCT_CODE                    MEMBER_TYPE STATUS COMPANY                                                                          CH_COL_REGION                  CM_CURRENT_INIT CH_CHAP_NUMBER Expr1
------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------- ----------- ------ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ --------------- -------------- -----------
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-01 13:18:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Omega Chapter                                                                    REG_5                          160             024            121
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-01 11:47:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Omega Chapter                                                                    REG_5                          160             024            121
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-01 21:24:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 15:39:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-08-31 12:23:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-12-07 00:00:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Gamma Psi Chapter                                                                REG_5                          84              095            56
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 16:01:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Beta Sigma Chapter                                                               REG_8                          172             066            6
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-08 09:14:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Beta Eta Chapter                                                                 REG_5                          127             055            85
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 22:44:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Epsilon Nu Chapter                                                               REG_7                          189             133            129
FIDELITYOL    2015-08-31 20:50:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Epsilon Pi Chapter                                                               REG_2                          149             136            68
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-01 08:03:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-08-31 22:19:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Epsilon Pi Chapter                                                               REG_2                          149             136            68
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-05 16:29:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 22:25:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Beta Sigma Chapter                                                               REG_8                          172             066            6
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-01 20:58:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Beta Sigma Chapter                                                               REG_8                          172             066            6
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 13:25:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 16:14:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-04 23:34:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
FIDELITYOL    2015-09-07 14:27:00.000 AAOL                            COL         A      Zeta Rho Chapter                                                                 REG_3                          282             161            162
```

Comment: SQL Server via MS Visual Studio

Comment: show us sample data and desire output so we can understand the problem,

Comment: If you want one row per company and there are multiple rows per company in the result set then you will have to group by company and also aggregate all the other fields : max, min, Group By, etc.

Comment: updated approved edit. new to this forum and still figuring it out. thanks for your patience.

Comment: In your results, please show all data returned as you have more columns in your select than you do in your results posted here.  That's where you may have non-distinct values.

Comment: What do you get from this query? `SELECT a2.ID, COUNT(a2.PRODUCT_CODE)
           FROM Activity AS a2
           WHERE (n2.COMPANY = Name.COMPANY)
           AND (a2.PRODUCT_CODE = 'aaol') 
           AND (a2.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', 102)
           AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-07-31 00:00:00', 102))
           GROUP BY a2.ID`

Comment: I get the total number of events via the PRODUCT_CODE associated with a COMPANY between a specific datetime. working on full output.

Comment: @db_brad Complete output (truncated) is at the bottom of the original question. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonTylerVaughn I only see one record in the complete output.

Comment: @db_brad Here's part of the output generated in MS Visual Studio where I'm working. (Screen Shot attached) I'm sorry I'm still figuring out how to get stuff to display properly in this forum - [link]http://imgur.com/u89jVJg

Comment: @JasonTylerVaughn I noticed in that screenshot that 2 of your columns, Transaction_Date and ID do not have distinct values in each of the groupings, sets.  That's why you are not getting distinct results for the other columns.  The entire record (all included columns) have to be distinct. Do you want to include those columns, yet only have 1 result per Company value?

Comment: @db_brad That is the idea, yes. The Transaction_Date is included because I'm filtering between a span of time 8/31/2015 and 7/31/2016. And truth be told, I don't think the ID does needs to be included going back over my original build document from the client. I think that's an error on their part.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works, its hard to tell without knowing what your data looks like:

```
DECLARE @transDateStart DATETIME='20150801';
DECLARE @transDateEnd DATETIME='20160731';
DECLARE @productCode VARCHAR(10) = 'aaol';

WITH CompanyActivityCount
     AS
        (SELECT DISTINCT       COUNT(a2.PRODUCT_CODE) AS Expr1, 
                       n2.COMPANY
         FROM Activity AS a2
         INNER JOIN
         Name AS n2
         ON a2.ID = n2.ID
         WHERE a2.PRODUCT_CODE = @productCode
               AND a2.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN @transDateStart AND @transDateEnd
         GROUP BY n2.COMPANY
        )
     SELECT DISTINCT    Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE, 
                    Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
                    Activity.PRODUCT_CODE, 
                    Activity.DESCRIPTION, 
                    Name.ID, 
                    Name.MEMBER_TYPE, 
                    Name.STATUS, 
                    Name.COMPANY, 
                    Demo_Chapter.CH_COL_REGION, 
                    Demo_Ch_Membership.CM_CURRENT_INIT, 
                    Demo_Chapter.CH_CHAP_NUMBER, 
                    CompanyActivityCount.Expr1
     FROM Name
     INNER JOIN
     Demo_Individual
     ON Name.ID = Demo_Individual.ID
     INNER JOIN
     Activity
     ON Name.ID = Activity.ID
     INNER JOIN
     Demo_Chapter
     ON Name.CO_ID = Demo_Chapter.ID
     INNER JOIN
     Demo_Ch_Membership
     ON Name.CO_ID = Demo_Ch_Membership.ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CompanyActivityCount
     ON CompanyActivityCount.COMPANY = Name.COMPANY
     WHERE Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'COL'
           AND Name.STATUS IN ('A', 'ABR')
           AND Activity.ACTIVITY_TYPE IN ('FIDELITY', 'FIDELITYOL')
           AND Activity.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN @transDateStart AND @transDateEnd
           AND Activity.PRODUCT_CODE = @productCode;
```

It should perform a little bit better too since there is no nested subquery.

Comment: Here is what you code returned. I re-edited my post with a more thorough output reading - http://imgur.com/nidB407

Answer (score -2):

Just use a DISTINCT in your select

Comment: OP already say DISTINCT doesnt work. Either show a different way or show why DISTICT work

Comment: It's your TRANSACTION_DATE  field that's preventing the DISTINCT from happening. The times are different.  You can either remove the date or simplify it to a calendar date (removing the time aspect)